# How to upgrade Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04

How can I upgrade my distribution of Ubuntu to the latest version? I am running 14.04 currently.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 14.04 is the lastest LTS (long-term stable) version.  You can upgrade to 14.10, with the [following instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UtopicUpgrades).

Run the update-manager application from the Unity Dash or a command line

In Update Manager, click the Settings... button, and enter your password to start the Software Sources application.

Select the sub menu Updates from the Software Sources application.
Confirm the "Notify me of a new Ubuntu version:" option is set to "For any new version", and change it if otherwise.
Close the Software Sources application and return to Update Manager.

In Update Manager, click the Check button to check for new updates.

If there are any updates to install, use the Install Updates button to install them, and press Check again after that is complete.
A message will appear informing you of the availability of the new release.

Click Upgrade.
Follow the on-screen instructions.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually update your Ubuntu by running the following commands in a Terminal ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> ):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Additionally you can run:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Software & Update, se the mid tab Updates, Se the notify at bottom, chose Notify me "for Any new vertion" Then you will be asked if you want to upgrade to 14.10 !
or use terminal *sudo apt-get update* followed by 'sudo apt-get upgrade'
Happy Ubunting.